# How do I omit the final comma (,) from output in C?

Tags: c

I have written this code to print out all prime numbers between 1 and the input value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
//Declaration of variables:
    int N, i, j, isPrime, n;

// Ask user for input the upper limit for the generation of primes (N)
printf("Enter the value of N\n");
scanf("%d",&N);

if (N==1){
    printf("There are no prime numbers before 1. Please recompile. \n" ); //print out an error if 
    // 1 is inputted as the upper limit for the generation of primes.
}

 /* For every number between 2 to N, check whether it is prime number or not */

else
    printf("The primes between 1 and %d are:  ", N);

for(i = 2; i <= N; i++){
    isPrime = 0;

        /* Check whether i is prime or not */
        for(j = 2; j <= i/2; j++){

        /* Check If any number between 2 to i/2 divides I completely If it divides, the numebr cannot be a prime. */

            if(i % j == 0){
                isPrime = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        // print out the primes if the conditions are met

    if(isPrime == 0 && N != 1)
        printf("%d, ", i);
}

return 0;
}
```

It works great, but I get a comma after each value, including the last one. I would like to remove the comma from being displayed just from the last one.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best.

Comment: By printing `2` first, and then *prepending* the comma instead of *appending* it

Comment: `printf("%d, ", i)` writes a comma after every number. You'll need to change that. Think about what you would do when writing out the list on paper and try to convert that into program code.

Comment: Knowing that `2` is a prime number you can skip that from the calculations and print `2` and then on subsequent output position the comma *before* the number (oops similar to @StoryTeller).

Comment: Depending on your terminal, you could also use `printf("\b\b ")` which would go back (\b) two places and overwrite the comma with space.

Comment: @Lucian and if the output is redirected to file ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is somewhat difficult to determine which iteration of the loop is the last one, one could put the comma *before* the output instead of *after* the output and omit the first comma as follows, where the comments are deleted for brevity.

```
int isFistIteraion = 0;
for(i = 2; i <= N; i++)
{
    isPrime = 0;
    for(j = 2; j <= i/2; j++){
        if(i % j == 0){
          isPrime = 1;
          break;
        }
    }
    if(IsPrime == 0 && N != 1){
        if (0 == isFirstIteration){
            isFirstIteraion = 1;
            printf("%d", i);
        } else {
            printf(", %d", i);
        }
    }
}
```